# Reference pointers to C++ objects in swift?

Tags: c++, swift, swift3

I'm working on a swift project which incorporates a C++ library (bullet physics).  Currently I achieve this by wrapping the C++ library with Objective-C, and then using the Objectve-C Code in Swift via bridging header.

I would like to eliminate the Objective-C wrapper, and access Bullet through a pure C interface in the interest of making the code more platform agnostic.

Conceptually, I understand how to create a C interface for C++ code by using `extern "C"`, but I don't know how to make the types from the C++ library available in my Swift Code.

For instance, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
// MyPhysicsObject.swift

class MyPhysicsObject {

    let rigidBody: btRigidBody

    init() {
        self.rigidBody = createRigidBody()  //called from C interface
    }

}
```

With a C header file:

```
// BulletCInterface.h

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

btRigidBody* createRigidBody();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And a C++ implementation file:

```
//BulletCInterface.cpp

#import <BulletDynamics/btBulletCollisionCommon.h>
#import <BulletDynamics/btBulletDynamicsCommon.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

btRigidBody* createRigidBody() {
   //invoke the C++ bullet API to produce a btRigid body
   //...
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

But when I attempt this, the compiler complains that `btRigidBody` is an undefined type in `BulletCInterface.h`.  At a minimum I would like to be able to hold references to these objects in swift, and at best I would like to be able to access their data members (like mass etc.)

How can I expose these C++ types to my Swift code?  Or do I have to just make everything a `void*` and keep track of types myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in Swift documentation, "You cannot import C++ code directly into Swift. Instead, create an Objective-C or C wrapper for C++ code." See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/.

If you want to keep Objective-C out of the picture, then you need a C wrapper, which is what you are trying to do.  You need to wrap C++ types in the C interface callable from Swift.  The error about `btRigidBody` is due to the type not being wrapped.  I'm assuming it is a C++ type and its definition is unavailable in the C interface header.  If you include a header that defines that type in `BulletCInterface.h`, that won't work because then it won't be usable in Swift via a bridging header.

The wrapper C interface could have functions that map to methods and data members of the C++ classes you use.

BTW, you don't need `#ifdef __cplusplus` in `BulletCInterface.cpp`, just do

```
// This should return a C wrapper for the btRigidBody C++ type
extern "C" btRigidBodyWrapper* createRigidBody() {
    ...
}
```

It's all C++ code, so you can use `extern "C"` without the pre-processor conditionals.

Hopefully this is helpful.