# converting C++ struct into swift with convention C compatible

Tags: c++, swift, dylib

Say I have an example struct in C++ that is inside dylib like this

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
} addingTemp;
```

and I need to use it for a function that adds 2 together, and store it into 3rd value

```
void add(addingTemp a, addingTemp b, addingTemp& c) {
    c.a = a.a + b.a;
}
```

how do I create the struct in swift?
this is my adding library function in swift

```
    typealias add = @convention(c) (addingTemp, addingTemp, UnsafeMutablePointer<addingTemp>) -> Void

    func addLib(a :  addingTemp, b:  addingTemp, out: inout addingTemp) -> Void{
        guard dylib != nil  else {
            errorDylib()
            return
        }
        guard let sym = dlsym(dylib, "add")  else {
            errorDylib()
            return
        }
        
        let f = unsafeBitCast(sym, to:add.self )
        
        let result : Void = f(a ,b, &out)
     //   closeDylib()
        return
    }
```

this is my current implementation

```
public class addingTemp: NSObject {
    public var a : CInt
    init(a: CInt = 0) {
        self.a = a
    }
}
```

but it gives me memory access error, it looks like it isn't being stored properly as the type doesn't match.

```
DLL_PUBLIC void add(
        addingTemp a,
        addingTemp b,
        addingTemp* c,);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference pointers to C++ objects in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202144/reference-pointers-to-c-objects-in-swift)

Comment: I believe I tried implementing the answer you posted. I edited at the end and that is what I have. the problem is that whenever I edit a value or return a struct (in c++) and add it into my class (swift), the value stored is not available to be accessed by my swift class.